# Add column to text file where the value is the row number?

Tags: text-processing

How do I add a column to a text file, where the value is the row number?

File before:

```
Foo Ba Lk Q
Lorem ipsum doler
```

File after

```
1 Foo Ba Lk Q
2 Lorem ipsum doler
```

etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few different approaches:

1. cat

   ```
   $ cat -n file
       1   Foo Ba Lk Q
       2   Lorem ipsum doler
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -pe 's/^/$. /' file
   ```

   The `-pe` means "print each input line after applying the  script given by `-e` to it". Then, we replace `^` (the beginning of the line) with the line number (`$.`) and a space.

   Alternatively, since this is Perl and [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it):

   ```
   perl -ne 'print "$. $_"' file 
   perl -pe '$_ = "$. $_"' file
   ```

   In all of these examples, if you want to modify the original file, use `-i`:

   ```
   perl -i -pe 's/^/$. /' file
   perl -i -ne 'print "$. $_"' file 
   perl -i -pe '$_ = "$. $_"' file
   ```
3. `awk`

   ```
   $ awk '{print NR,$0}' file
   1 Foo Ba Lk Q
   2 Lorem ipsum doler
   ```

   The special variable `NR` is the current line number and `$0` the current line. To make the change in the original file (assuming you have a recent enough version of GNU awk), do:

   ```
   gawk -iinplace '{print NR,$0}' file
   ```
4. `sed`

   ```
   $ sed = file | sed 'N;s/\n/\t/'
   1   Foo Ba Lk Q
   2   Lorem ipsum doler
   ```

   The `=` means "print the line number before every line". However, that prints the number on a line by itself and the input line under that. The second `sed` command puts them back on the same line again.

Comment: also the venerable `nl` of course

Comment: @steeldriver ah, I knew I was forgetting something obvious. Why don't you whip up a little answer?

Answer (score 4):

#### Just for fun

```
python3 -c "[print(i+1, l.strip())for i, l in enumerate(open('f').readlines())]"
```

Output:

```
1 Foo Ba Lk Q
2 Lorem ipsum doler
```

Where `f` is the path to your file, in quotes.

#### Explanation

```
open('f').readlines()
```

will read the file, in lines, and

```
enumerate(open('f').readlines())
```

will subsequently add a number to each of the lines, and

```
print(i+1, l.strip())
```

will print the number (+1, since the first index is 0) + the corresponding line